# Sending email using sp_send_dbmail() does not work sometimes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sp-send-dbmail

I am sending notification email using SQL Server but sometimes emails aren't sent to users.

Here is my SQL table that I store emails which it will be sent to users

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmailNotification](
[Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[EmailAdress] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
[EmailBody] [NVARCHAR](500) NULL,
[EmailSubject] [NVARCHAR](250) NULL,
[Attachment] [NVARCHAR](500) NULL,
[EmailSent] [BIT] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_EmailNotification_EmailSent]  DEFAULT 
((0)),
[EmailCreateDate] [DATETIME] NULL CONSTRAINT 
[DF_EmailNotification_EmailCreateDate]  DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
[EmailSentDate] [DATETIME] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_EmailNotification] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And I have created a job which executes this procedure every 1 minute

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSendEmail] 
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @id BIGINT
DECLARE @max_id BIGINT
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @EmailBody NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @EmailAdress NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @EmailSubject NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @attachments NVARCHAR(1000)

if exists (SELECT * FROM dbo.EmailNotification where EmailSent=0)
begin 
SELECT @id=MIN(id) FROM dbo.EmailNotification where EmailSent=0


SELECT @EmailAdress=EmailAdress,@EmailBody=EmailBody,@EmailSubject=EmailSubject,@attachments=Attachment
FROM EmailNotification WHERE id = @id


exec [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail] @profile_name='Notification',
@recipients=@EmailAdress,
@blind_copy_recipients='example.email.com',
@subject=@EmailSubject,
@body=@EmailBody,
@file_attachments=@attachments

end
IF(@@ERROR>0)
BEGIN
ROLLBACK
END
ELSE
BEGIN
UPDATE EmailNotification set EmailSent=1, EmailSentDate=getdate() WHERE Id=@id
COMMIT  
END
```

Comment: "Does not work". Do you mean they don't receive the email? First alter your code take note of the return value as mentioned below. Then check the SQL logs to see if there is any error mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean : spSendEmail is not triggering sp_send_dbmail? sp_send_dbmail is triggered but doesn't do anything....?

Please get the return code of sp_send_dbmail :
0 => OK
<> 0 => Error occured

```
DECLARE @result int;
DECLARE @ErrorNb int;
EXECUTE @result = exec [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail] @profile_name='EDMS email notification',
@recipients=@EmailAdress,
@blind_copy_recipients='example.email.com',
@subject=@EmailSubject,
@body=@EmailBody,
@file_attachments=@attachments
SET @ErrorNb = @@ERROR    

IF @result <> 0
BEGIN
-- Something goes wrong
SELECT @result,@ErrorNb  
END
```

You can also use TRY :

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXECUTE exec [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail] @profile_name='EDMS email notification',
    @recipients=@EmailAdress,
    @blind_copy_recipients='example.email.com',
    @subject=@EmailSubject,
    @body=@EmailBody,
    @file_attachments=@attachments
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH
```

Comment: Thanks for your response clementakis.I will try what you offer

Comment: Have you found out you problem? Hope so ^^

Comment: The problem was maximum attachment size exceeded sometimes:))

Comment: Ok, this value can be changed... Good night ^^

Comment: Hi, clementakis.Again I have a problem sending e-mail. When I see view history of the job there was some errors stating error message Id 22051 Attachment error.But I execute query manually it worked and then job started working correctly

Comment: SQL Server services must have rights to access the folder where you have put the attachment files... Note that the services must have right for the full path to the file, and to the file itself.

Comment: Use SELECT * FROM sys.dm_server_services to know what user is used for services. then you have to see what group this user is a part of... And then look at the windows right of each subdirectoris in the path of the file.

Comment: Hi, clementakis. I try your select statement it showed me service account is .\sqldb  and I am going to add this user to the folders and subfolders which I want to attach file from them but windows does not let me select this user

Comment: Windows is out of my knowledge scope : sorry. Maybe you could ask another question on this sepcifc problem...